# Adding a second Group By column slows query down

Tags: mysql, index, join, group-by

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 'TEXT', 'TYPE', 'DESTINATION', 'HEADLINE', 'COUNTRY_ID', 'COUNTRY_CODE'
UNION ALL
SELECT Data_1.TEXT, Data_1.TYPE, Data_2.Destination, Data_2.HEADLINE,
    Data_3.COUNTRY_ID, Data_4.Country_Code
FROM Data_1
LEFT JOIN Data_2 on Data_1.GROUP_ID=Data_2.GROUP_ID
LEFT JOIN Data_3 on Data_1.GROUP_ID=Data_3.GROUP_ID
LEFT JOIN Data_4 on Data_3.COUNTRY_ID=Data_4.COUNTRY_ID
WHERE Data_2.DESTINATION LIKE "%88327%"
GROUP BY Data_1.TEXT, Data_1.GROUP_ID
```

As long as I just have `GROUP BY Data_1.TEXT` everything is fine and the query is executed fast. But when adding a second field to group by like `GROUP BY Data_1.TEXT, Data_1.GROUP_ID` the query does not come to an end anymore. (In fact it needs about 2hrs for a LIMIT 10 query vs 0.06 sec using `GROUP BY Data_1.TEXT` only)

Profiling result:

```
+----------------------+----------+
| Status               | Duration |
+----------------------+----------+
| starting             | 0.000075 |
| checking permissions | 0.000005 |
| checking permissions | 0.000002 |
| checking permissions | 0.000004 |
| Opening tables       | 0.000026 |
| init                 | 0.000044 |
| System lock          | 0.000009 |
| optimizing           | 0.000017 |
| statistics           | 0.000053 |
| preparing            | 0.000019 |
| Creating tmp table   | 0.000025 |
| Sorting result       | 0.000004 |
| executing            | 0.000002 |
| Sending data         | 8.388898 |
| end                  | 0.000008 |
| removing tmp table   | 0.000227 |
| end                  | 0.000005 |
| query end            | 0.000007 |
| closing tables       | 0.000013 |
| freeing items        | 0.000016 |
| logging slow query   | 0.000024 |
| cleaning up          | 0.000010 |
+----------------------+----------+`
(stopped the query after approx. 10 sec)
```

I did a lot of reading regarding possible reasons, all articles mentioned there might be a wrong or missing index causing *sending data* to be extremely slow.

Explain of statement looks like this:

```
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-----------------------------------+--------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref                               | rows   | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-----------------------------------+--------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Data_1 | ALL  | GROUP_ID      | NULL       | NULL    | NULL                              | 981494 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Data_3 | ref  | GROUP_ID      | GROUP_ID   | 9       | reports_v201506.Data_1.ADGROUP_ID |      2 | NULL                            |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Data_4 | ref  | COUNTRY_ID    | COUNTRY_ID | 768     | reports_v201506.Data_3.COUNTRY_ID |      1 | NULL                            |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Data_2 | ref  | GROUP_ID      | GROUP_ID   | 9       | reports_v201506.Data_1.ADGROUP_ID |     36 | Using where                     |
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-----------------------------------+--------+---------------------------------+
```

It seems no key is used for Data_1 table. But the following index is set:

```
+--------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table  | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+--------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Data_1 |          1 | TEXT     |            1 | TEXT        | A         |       75499 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| Data_1 |          1 | GROUP_ID |            1 | GROUP_ID    | A         |       23368 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+--------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
+--------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table  | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+--------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Data_2 |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | ROW_ID      | A         |      557211 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| Data_2 |          1 | GROUP_ID |            1 | GROUP_ID    | A         |       15478 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+--------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
+--------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table  | Non_unique | Key_name   | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+--------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Data_3 |          0 | PRIMARY    |            1 | ROW_ID      | A         |       44782 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| Data_3 |          1 | GROUP_ID   |            1 | GROUP_ID    | A         |       22391 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| Data_3 |          1 | COUNTRY_ID |            1 | COUNTRY_ID  | A         |         285 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+--------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
+--------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table  | Non_unique | Key_name     | Seq_in_index | Column_name  | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+--------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Data_4 |          1 | COUNTRY_ID   |            1 | COUNTRY_ID   | A         |       86652 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| Data_4 |          1 | COUNTRY_Code |            1 | COUNTRY_Code | A         |        1733 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+--------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Please find below the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE Data_1`

```
+-------------------+------------------------------------+
| Table             | Create Table                       
+-------------------+------------------------------------+
| Data_1 | CREATE TABLE `Data_1` (
  `ROW_ID` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ACCOUNT_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DATE_END` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DATE_RANGE_TYPE` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DATE_START` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PARTNER_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TIMESTAMP` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `TOP_ACCOUNT_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ACCOUNT_DESCRIPTIVE_NAME` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ACCOUNTTIMEZONEID` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CUSTOMER_DESCRIPTIVE_NAME` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DAY` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `DAYOFWEEK` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IMPRESSIONS` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MONTH` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `MONTH_OF_YEAR` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PRIMARYCOMPANYNAME` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `QUARTER` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `WEEK` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `YEAR` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GROUP_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GROUP_NAME` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TEXT` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `STATUS` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `URL_CUSTOM_PARAMETERS` longtext,
  KEY `TEXT` (`TEXT`),
  KEY `GROUP_ID` (`GROUP_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
+-------------------+------------------------------------+
```

Please find below the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE Data_2`

```
+-------------+----------------------------------------------+
| Table       | Create Table                                 
+-------------+----------------------------------------------+
| Data_2 | CREATE TABLE `Data_2` (
  `ROW_ID` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ACCOUNT_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DATE_END` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DATE_RANGE_TYPE` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DATE_START` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PARTNER_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TIMESTAMP` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `TOP_ACCOUNT_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ACCOUNT_DESCRIPTIVE_NAME` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ACCOUNTTIMEZONEID` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CUSTOMER_DESCRIPTIVE_NAME` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DAY` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `DAYOFWEEK` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IMPRESSIONS` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MONTH` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `MONTH_OF_YEAR` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PRIMARYCOMPANYNAME` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `QUARTER` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `WEEK` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `YEAR` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GROUP_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GROUP_NAME` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CONTENT_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `STATUS` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CONTENT_TYPE` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AVERAGE_PAGEVIEWS` decimal(19,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AVERAGE_TIME_ON_SITE` decimal(19,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BOUNCE_RATE` decimal(19,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DESTINATION` longtext,
  `HEADLINE` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LABELS` longtext,
  `CONTENT1` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CONTENT2` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ROW_ID`),
  KEY `GROUP_ID` (`GROUP_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
+-------------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Please find below the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE Data_3`

```
+--------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| Table        | Create Table                          
+--------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| Data_3 | CREATE TABLE `Data_3` (
  `ROW_ID` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ACCOUNT_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DATE_END` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DATE_RANGE_TYPE` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DATE_START` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PARTNER_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TIMESTAMP` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `TOP_ACCOUNT_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ACCOUNT_DESCRIPTIVE_NAME` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ACCOUNTTIMEZONEID` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NETWORK` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DAY` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `DAYOFWEEK` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IMPRESSIONS` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MONTH` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `MONTH_OF_YEAR` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PRIMARYCOMPANYNAME` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `QUARTER` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `WEEK` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `YEAR` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FORMAT` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GROUP_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GROUP_NAME` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GROUP_STATUS` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CITY_ID` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `COUNTRY_ID` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LOCATION_TYPE` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `METRO_ID` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `REGION_ID` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ROW_ID`),
  KEY `ADGROUP_ID` (`ADGROUP_ID`),
  KEY `COUNTRY_ID` (`COUNTRY_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
+--------------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

Please find below the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE Data_4`

```
+---------------------+----------------------------------------------+
| Table               | Create Table                                 |
+---------------------+----------------------------------------------+
| Data_4 | CREATE TABLE `Data_4` (
  `COUNTRY_ID` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(60) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Canonical_Name` varchar(83) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Parent_ID` varchar(7) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Country_Code` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Target_Type` varchar(22) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Status` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `COUNTRY_ID` (`COUNTRY_ID`),
  KEY `Country_Code` (`Country_Code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
+---------------------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Quick explanation of purpose and content of tables:

- Data_1 contains report data regarding tags usage (usage = impressions)
- Data_2 contains report data regarding content usage (usage = impressions)
- Data_3 contains report data regarding geographical usage (usage = impressions)
- Data_4 contains a table for matching ISO country codes

What's my mistake?

Comment: You should check (and add) EXPLAINs for BOTH versions (slow and fast), so they can be compared. Add relevant `show create table <name>;` too (for instance the type of the column `TEXT` might be quite important).

Comment: The explain above ist already with removed `SELECT 'TEXT', 'TYPE', 'DESTINATION', 'HEADLINE', 'COUNTRY_ID', 'COUNTRY_CODE' UNION ALL`.

Comment: And there is no difference between the explain for the slow and the fast version.

Comment: Remove the images and add the `EXPLAIN` output in text and the outputs of `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;`. They are far more useful than the `SHOW index`.

Comment: @GinkoDinko are you sure they are exactly the same? no change in the `rows` or `extra` columns. If it is so, then try running the "slow" version two times to see if it is fast the second time (reason would be warmed-up caches)

Comment: @jkavalik the results are exactly the same and it doesn't change when running the "slow" versions two times. I did reset the query cache `RESET QUERY CACHE;`but still the same result when running the "slow" version.

Comment: @GinkoDinko `Data_1` and `Data_4` do not have any primary key. Thats probably not the reason for slow queries but is probably not what you want - you have no unique key so there may be duplicated records.

Comment: @GinkoDinko "alter table Data_1 add key(`TEXT`, `GROUP_ID`)" will create index which can be used for the `GROUP BY` over those two fields. Unfortunately `Data_2.DESTINATION LIKE "%88327%"` cannot use any index so your query has to read entire tables. And you are probably abusing the `GROUP BY` by selecting columns which are neither grouped nor aggregated (either that or the `GROUP BY` has no real effect - why are you grouping when you do no sums, counts etc).

Comment: @jkavalik I added the key as you suggested and the querys' time was `10 rows in set (0.01 sec)' - obviously solved the problem! Thank you! (blame on me I did not thought about this basic fact by myself...)

Comment: @jkavalik reason for the `GROUP BY` is to avoid duplicates but to catch all combinations available. I tried the query with a `SELECT DISINCT' first but since the `DESTINATION` filed contains added tracking parameters I got a lot results which only differ regarding the paraameters within the `DESTINATION' field (which are deleted after export). Does that sound reasonable to you?

Comment: @GinkoDinko then you should not select `DESTINATION` as its value after grouping does not make any sense (one of those possible values will be picked "randomly"). Or you should decide which one to use (min() and max() should work on text fields but I would not do that, the same for group_concat() so I suggest not to select it at all, at least not in this query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data_1 needs `INDEX(text, group_id)`
Data_2 needs `INDEX

Other notes:

- It is better to use realistic limits, not "255" blindly.
- It is better to explicitly provide a `PRIMARY KEY` for InnoDB tables.
- But `VARCHAR(255)` is a poor choice for a `PRIMARY KEY`.
- Are `group_id` and `group_name` in a 1-to-1 relationship?  If so, build a table describing that; don't simply hide it in some other table.
- `BIGINT` takes 8 bytes; `INT UNSIGNED` handles values 0 to 4 billion.  Do you really expect more than 4 billion 'partners', 'groups', etc?
- If `DATE_START` is a "date" or a "datetime", don't use `VARCHAR(255)`, you won't be able to do comparisons, ranges, arithmetic, etc.
- Is `Data_2.DESTINATION` really a `LONGTEXT` that might have '88327' buried somewhere in the middle?  If it is at the start (or alone), then there is a much better way to do the query.

Also...

```
`Country_Code` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
```

-->

```
`Country_Code` CHAR(2) DEFAULT NULL CHARACTER SET ascii,
```

And then make it the `PRIMARY KEY` of Data_4.  And Get rid of `country_code`.

After you have made most of these recommendations, we can look again at whether `GROUP BY` is still giving trouble.